# Character Sequenceに対応するキー入力を調べたい

Tags: bash

Bashの対話環境はキーバインドの設定(特定のキー入力に対して特定のコマンドを実行)を行うことができます。現在の設定は`bind -P`で確認することができます。

しかし、この時のキーの表示(character sequence)はわかりにくいものになっています。
例えば、↑キーのcharacter sequenceは、`[A`です。
これは以下の手順で確認できます:

1. 端末上でCtrl+Vを押す。
2. 続けて↑を押すと、^[[Aと表示される。
3. ^[はエスケープを表す記号なので気にしない。[Aが↑のcharacter sequenceである。

**質問**: 逆に、与えられたcharacter sequenceがどのようなキー入力に対応するのかを調べるにはどうすればよいのでしょうか?

---

動機: なぜこれが知りたいのかというと、私の`.bashrc`には

```
bind '"\e[0A": history-search-backward'
```

と書いてあるのですが、この`"\e[0A"`が何のcharacter sequenceに相当するのかわからなくて困っています。あまり意味がないものなら消してしまいたいのですが....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bind '"\e[0A": history-search-backward'
```

まず、`\e[0A` はもしかして `\e[OA` ではないでしょうか？

キー入力の確認についてですが、terminal(端末)の制御に terminfo を使用されているとして話を進めます。まず、infocmp コマンドを実行して現在使用中の端末の設定を確認します。

```
$ infocmp | less
```

表示されている内容から、`[A` か `OA` を検索します。

```
cup=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dH, cuu=\E[%p1%dA, cuu1=\E[A,
kcub1=\EOD, kcud1=\EOB, kcuf1=\EOC, kcuu1=\EOA,
```

対応する制御シーケンス名が、`cuu1` か `kcuu1` だと分かるかと思います。

次に、terminfo の man を確認します。

```
$ man terminfo
```

そこで `cuu1` を検索すると、カーソルキー(↑)だと分かります。

```
Variable   Cap-  TCap   Description
String     name  Code

cursor_up  cuu1  up     up one line
key_up     kcuu1 ku     up-arrow key
```

もっとも、この調べ方はかなり煩雑かと思います。また、terminfo ではなく termcap を使われている場合には当てはまりませんので、ご参考程度までにどうぞ。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。大変参考になります。おっしゃる通り元々は`\e[0A`ではなく`\e[OA`だったのかもしれません。

キーボードからの入力がどのように処理されるのかあまり理解していないのですが、例えば`↑`キーを入力するとterminfoに情報が渡されるのですか?

あと、`kcuu1`の方は何かのキーに対応するのでしょうか?

Comment: 端末上で↑キーを押すと、端末エミュレータ(xtermなど)側では「カーソルを一行上へ移動させる」処理を実行しようとします。その処理を端末上で実行するためにはどの様な制御シーケンスを発生させればよいのかをterminfoに問い合わせて、`\e[OA`というシーケンスを受け取ることになります。ですので、terminfo自体は端末情報データベースといった位置づけになります。`kcuu1`についてですが、`man terminfo`を読むとキーパッドやテンキーに付いているカーソルキーに対応している様です(テンキー付きのキーボードを持っていないのでよく分かりません(苦笑))。

Answer (score 2):

手順としては、 heliac2001 さんのものと同じで

- `infocmp` で、設定エントリを検索
- `man 5 terminfo` のなかで、対応する行を見つける

です。一行で書けば、

```sh
$ infocmp -1x | grep 'OA' \
   | sed 's/^ *//' | tee /dev/tty | sed 's/=.*$//' \
   | xargs -l sh -c 'man 5 terminfo | grep -F "  $0  "'
```

となりますが、面倒。ですので逆引きを行うスクリプトを作成してみました。

ファイル: `terminfo_lookup.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# Reverse terminfo lookup command.

param_code=$1
param_term=$2

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 [part of a terminfo entry] [termname]"
  echo "Example:"
  echo "        $0 kent"
  echo "        $0 OA xterm"
  echo "        $0 kcuu1 putty"
  echo "        $0 \\\\EA rxvt"
  echo "        $0 kf1= xterm"
  exit 1
fi

echo "Searching for \"$param_code\"."
if [ -z "$2" ]; then
  echo "TERM value is \"$TERM (default)\"."
else
  echo "TERM value is \"$param_term\"."
fi

entries=`infocmp -1x $param_term \
  | grep '=' | grep -F $param_code \
  | sed 's/=^ *//' | sed 's/,$//'`

if [ -z "$entries" ]; then
  echo "No entry found"
  exit 1
fi

for entry in $entries
do
 echo ---
 echo "entry :" $entry

 code=`echo $entry | sed 's/=.*$//'`
 hint=`man 5 terminfo 2> /dev/null | grep "  $code  " `
 echo "hint  :" $hint
done
```

使うときは、コマンドの引数に terminfo の設定エントリの一部を渡してください。

質問内容に沿う調査ならば、

```
$ terminfo_lookup.sh [OA
```

で必要な情報を確認し、

```
$ terminfo_lookup.sh cuu
$ terminfo_lookup.sh cuu rxvt
```

で関連情報や環境による差異を掘り下げて調査します。学習には使えるかと思います。

Comment: これは便利ですね。シェルスクリプトの書き方も参考にもなりますし、どうもありがとうございます。