# GNU screenで、分割画面を逆回し

Tags: centos, putty

ターミナル上で、screenを分割すると、ctrl-aでコマンドモードにして、tabを押すと、
順番に分割画面が切り替わりますが、逆順に切り替える方法はありますか？

なにかで、shitf + tabを押すとできるというのを見たような覚えがあるのですが、
押しても一瞬コピーモードになって、すぐコピーモードが終わるだけです。
バージョンを見ると、Screen version 4.00.03 なので、
これも起因しているのでしょうか。

ターミナルソフトはputtyを使用しており、CentOSを使用しています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:focus up` じゃないでしょうか？man screenに以下の記述がありました。
shift + tabで動くようにするにはbindさせる必要がありそうですね。

```
focus [up|down|top|bottom]

Move the input focus to the next region. This is done in a cyclic way so that
the top region is selected after the bottom one. If no subcommand is given it
defaults to `down'. `up' cycles in the opposite order, `top' and `bottom' go to
the top  and  bottom  region  respectively.

Useful bindings are (j and k as in vi)
   bind j focus down
   bind k focus up
   bind t focus top
   bind b focus bottom
```

Comment: shift tabよりも便利ですね、kはセッションのkillにかぶりそうですが大文字でできるので、screenrcに追記することでうまいこと行きました。マニュアルに書いてあるなんて発想がありませんでした。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

私の環境では `~/.screenrc` に、以下を追加すると、 <kbd>Ctrl+a</kbd><kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd> が効くようになります。

```
bindkey -k kB focus up

bind j focus down
bind k focus up
bind t focus top
bind b focus bottom
```

※ `j` `k` `t` `b`は `man screen` から追加のサンプル

環境によって <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd> のコードが違うときがあると思われますので、そのときは、[この回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/2354/4978)の `termcap_lookup.sh` を使って適当に探してください。

```
$ ^[[Z    # <-- Ctrl+V Shift+Tab を押した
$ ./terminfo_lookup.sh [Z
Searching for "[Z".
TERM value is "xterm-256color (default)".
---
entry : cbt=\E[Z
hint  : back_tab cbt bt back tab (P)
---
entry : kcbt=\E[Z
hint  : key_btab kcbt kB back-tab key
```

Comment: 補足ありがとうございます。shift tabが効くようにできるなんて、思いもよりませんでした。